# Counting the number of surjective linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (where $p$ is prime), let $V=K^{n+1}$ and let $W=K^n$. I want to show that the number of surjective linear maps $f:V\to W$ is $$\frac{p^{n^2}(p^{n+1}-1)}{p-1}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p^{-i})$$

Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_{n+1}\}$ be a basis for $V$.
 I know that $W$ has $p^n$ elements and there are $p^n$ choices for where to send $v_1.$ I also see that I need the dimension of the kernel to be $1$ by the rank-nullity theorem. However, after this point I'm not sure what conditions I need to ensure that the maps are surjective.

EDIT:

Having considered the matrix idea given in the comments I have come up with the following:

We want $n$ linearly independent rows and so we have $p^{n+1}-1$ choices for the first row, $p^{n+1}-p$ for the second...  This then gives me an answer of $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(p^{n+1}-p^{i-1})$$

This seems logical to me but still isn't the correct answer.

Comment: Not totally necessary but useful to add that $p$ is a prime number and that every field is a vector space over itself (so "linear maps" have sense).

Comment: @Piquito Thank you, I've made an edit to my post.

Comment: So, you are looking for the number of $n \times (n+1)$ matrix which has rank $n$.

Comment: @i707107 So how would I go about ensuring that the matrix has rank $n$? Make sure the rows are linearly independent?

Comment: I remember seeing something similar to this in Stanley's "Enumerative Combinatorics" Trying to remember the solution..

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct. Some algebraic manipulations show that
$$
\frac{p^{n^2}(p^{n + 1} - 1)}{p - 1} \prod_{i = 1}^n (1 - p^{-i}) = \prod_{i = 1}^n (p^{n + 1} - p^{i - 1}).
$$
Here are the details
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i = 1}^n (p^{n + 1} - p^{i - 1}) &= p^{n(n + 1)} \prod_{i = 1}^n (1 - p^{i - n - 2}) \\
&= p^{n(n + 1)} \prod_{i = 1}^n (1 - p^{-i - 1}) \\
&= \frac{p^{n^2}(p^{n + 1} - 1)}{p - 1} \prod_{i = 1}^n (1 - p^{-i}).
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you show what these algebraic manipulations are please?

Comment: Added some details.

Comment: How did you get $p^{n(n+1)} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-p^{-i-1})$ from the previous equality?

Comment: This follows from $\prod_{i = 1}^n a_i = \prod_{i = 1}^n a_{n + 1 - i}$.

Comment: Why is that the case?

Comment: @user332597 This is the rearrangement of the product. From small index to large one, and large to small.

Comment: Also, it will be easier if you consider $(n+1)\times n$ matrix having linearly independent columns.

Comment: @i707107 Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean here by from small index to large and large to small?

Comment: @user332597 I thought that you were asking about $\prod_{i = 1}^n a_i = \prod_{i = 1}^n a_{n + 1 - i}$. The left side is from $i=1$ to $n$, while the right side is from $n+1-i = n$ to $n+1-i = 1$. This is what I meant by small to large and large to small index.

Comment: @i707107 Oh I see now, thank you! Where does the next equality come from?